# Applied for a Canadian Working Holiday Visa over six weeks ago and still haven't heard anything, should I be concerned?

Tags: visas, canada, australia, working-holiday, work

My boyfriend is Australian and applied for a working holiday visa on May 10, and the site said the processing time would be six weeks. We were under the impression this was the maximum time and he would hear back much before then. Does it usually take this long? Should we be concern?

Also he had to apply without his police certificate as it did not come in time. He received it a few days later and was told when his application was looked at he would be able to attach it. Could this be the reason his application is taking so long? When he does attach it is it going to be another six week wait?

Comment: Did he contact the embassy/consular staff about this ?

Comment: He sent an email a couple days ago but hasn't heard anything back yet.

Comment: Did he get a [conditional acceptance letter](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/international.asp)?

Comment: Yes he got the conditional acceptance letter and then sent in his application.

Comment: Any update? Did he get it?